# Difference of these to objects(Java Inheritance)

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Bz bz1 = new Bz();
        Az bz2 = new Bz(); // Perfectly possible.
    }
}

class Az
{

}

class Bz extends Az
{

}
```

Now, what I don't understand is why is it possible to create an object from the class `Az` like that.
And what difference are there.

This is just an example code, I will just like to know what the differences are.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an object from the class Az"? I suggest you read a tutorial on inheritance, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Person p = you; JavaDeveloper p2 = you; Both refer to you. When using p, the compiler only knows that you're a person, whereas when using p2, the compiler knows that you're a Java developer.

Comment: If `Bz` is a `Dog`, `Az` is an `Animal`, then it make sense, `Dog` is an `Animal` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if it makes more sense like this

```
class Cat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // 1)
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        // 2)
        Animal anotherCat = new Cat(); // Perfectly possible.
    }
}

class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}
```

In 1) you are creating a `Cat` object and you will expose all methods from `Cat` and from `Animal` since a `Cat` is an `Animal` (which in Java translates to `extends`).

In 2) you are creating a `Cat` object and you will expose all methods from `Animal`.

The difference lies in the fact that you are exposing two different interfaces to the world using `cat` and `anotherCat`.

For example, imagine you are writing a method that deals with feeding animals, the signature might be something like

```
public void abstract feed(Animal animal, Food food);
```

You just want an `Animal`, you don't care if it's a `Dog` or a `Cat`.
Once you write the implementation of `feed` you might want to say `animal.eat`, where `eat` will be a method on all `Animal`s.

Comment: This is a very easy to understand example of the question and basic inheritance!

Comment: You are most welcome, I hope it makes sense and I did not make any major mistake there :D

Answer (score 0):

Thats the exact relationship you are defining with extends. Bz "is a" Az (and somewhat more).
Like every thumb is a finger, but not every finger is a thumb.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "is a" relationship between the two classes. So `Bz` "is a" `Az`. That is why you can create an instance of `Bz` (`new Bz()`) by declaring the variable as its superclass type (`Az bz2`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to translate in another field:

```
    class ExampleClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cat bz1 = new Cat();
        Animal bz2 = new Cat(); // Perfectly possible.
    }
}

class Animal
{

}

class Cat extends Animal
{

}
```

Cat is a Cat but also an Animal. This is the simple concept of subclass inheritance.

Comment: We came up with exactly the same example :D

Comment: Perhaps italians love cats a lot... I really do

Answer (score 0):

The parent/super class can be seen as a generalization of the child class.
This is used like this for example:

```
class Person
{
    public void talk()
    {
        System.out.println("I am a Person");
    }
}

class Student extends Person
{
    @Override
    public void talk()
    {
        System.out.println("I am a Student (also a Person)");
    }
}

class Test()
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(new Person());
        people.add(new Student());  //ok, because a student IS also a person

        //Will call the "right" methode, we only care about people and not the student details.
        for(Person person : people)
           person.talk();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bz bz1 = new Bz();
```

The object bz1 will not support run time polymorphism.

Default implementation of some method in superclass wont be executed in case child class Bz doesnt make its own.

```
 Az bz2 = new Bz();
```

The object bz2 will support run time polymorphism and will be able to support other of its subclass declarations, if you happen to create any. Since its an inheritance **is-A** UML relation so such declarations are possible.

Default implementation of some method in superclass will be executed in case child class Bz doesnt make its own.

All polymorhism aspects of Object oriented programing would be supported in the second case whereas the the first case would be a standalone class. However it'll inherit parent class attributes.